# converting object to string has error

Tags: c#, .net, string

My code is this :

```
SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(ClsPublic.GetConnectionString());
                   SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE (Blogger = @Blogger)", scn);
                   scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Blogger", lblBloger.Text);
                   scn.Open();
                   MyLabel.Text = scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                   scn.Close();
```

in this line :

```
lblLastNo.Text = scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Has this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

or when I using if statement , shows same error

```
object Blogger= "";
if (Blogger.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    ....
}
```

in below code again shows same error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `scm.ExecuteScalar()` is bringing you a null value. You need to test the value returned before using it:

```
var result = scm.ExecuteScalar();
MyLabel.Text = result == null ? '' : result.ToString();
```

Comment: @gbianchi At first I thought of that too but `DBNull.Value.ToString()` does not fail, it results in empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`scm.ExecuteScalar()` is returning null, or `scm` is null, or `lblLastNo` is null.  That's the only reason you get the error 'Object reference not set ..'.

Comment: Sometimes returns Null and Sometimes returns a value .. when it is returning a value I have no problem but when it is returning null shows error ..

Comment: @Persian. - So check if the value is **null** before you try to cast it.  If the object is a null you can assign the value of your result string to **null** since a null object if it was nullable would return **null** of course this begs the question why not get the string value back instead?

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteScalar return an Object type. This is why you have the same behavior on `scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` or `Blogger.ToString()`.

The object type default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object, as the following example shows.

If this object is NULL, you will receive the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Your second case with :

```
object blogger= "";
if (blogger.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    ....
}
```

Should not throw an Exception but return a string that represents the object instance. For example : `"YourNameSpace.Blogger"`

Answer (score -1):

Please enclose with try catch block, so that you can handle runtime exceptions and its makes life easier to understand the problem. and for `if (Blogger.ToString() != string.Empty)` this u can check for Null condition or if its string.  Then you can check for `String.IsNullorEmpty`

```
  string str=blogger.toString();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) 
            //do something
   else 
     //do other part
```

[String Is Null or EMpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Comment: Dear Ravi , when blogger is null , it can't convert blogger to string type and shows error .. in your first line of code has error

Comment: i assumed that u already handled that null condition.. i mentioned for string.. any way will check for blogger object for null. thanks for finding mistake.. :)